# PHP regex replace from data array

Tags: php, regex

I have a template string like this

```
$myStr ="<font face=\"#3#\" size=\"6\">TEST STRING</font>";
```

And an array of fonts like this

```
$fontList = array(
    0 => "ubuntumono",
    1 => "opensans",
    2 => "opensanscondensed",
    3 => 'opensanslight',
    4 => 'exo2',
    5 => 'exo2light'
);
```

Now I want to check my string for `face=\"#3#\"` (3 is the index of font in $fontList)

and replace it with `face=\"opensanslight\"`

How can I do it with Regex & PHP? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming PHP 5.3.0 or better:

```
$myStr = preg_replace_callback('/#(\d+)#/', function ($matches) use ($fontList) {
    return $fontList[$matches[1]];
}, $myStr);
```

[Example](http://ideone.com/JKC3nJ)

If you want to only change `#number#` when it is surrounded by quotes:

```
$myStr = preg_replace_callback('/"#(\d+)#"/', function ($matches) use ($fontList) {
    return '"' . $fontList[$matches[1]] . '"';
}, $myStr);
```

[Example](http://ideone.com/ujPlJd)

Comment: the index in `$matches` should be zero? if i'm not wrong

Comment: No.  `$matches[0]` would be `#3#`.  `$matches[1]` would be `3`.

Comment: ohh ok. nice answer (Y)

Comment: Thank you @Sean Bright for your rapid reply but I want to ask something more. I guess this solution will also change other parts of the string Ex: `<font face=\"#3#\" size=\"6\">TEST #114# another occurence</font>`.How can I solve this problem. By the way $fontList array may have more than 100 fonts. Thank you.

Comment: @user3253797: I made an edit that will make it only match when surrounded by quotes.  Does that satisfy your needs?

Comment: @bodi0: Where would you use `preg_quote` here?  None of the arguments to `preg_replace_callback` need to be escaped.